# Jersey Rest Service with HTTP basic security not taking user

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, jersey

I have spent almost 4 days researching how can I achieve a http basic auth using Jersey running in Weblogic 12c.

I have found these tutorials that are very close about what I want:

http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-secure-jersey-rest-services-with-spring-security-and-basic-authentication/

https://github.com/JohnathanMarkSmith/springmvc-rest-secured-test

I am using Weblogic 12c, these is my Spring xml security:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

    <!-- Stateless RESTful services use BASIC authentication -->
    <http create-session="stateless"                    
                   pattern="/rest/**" 
                   authentication-manager-ref="myAuthenticationManager">
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="ROLE_REST"/>
        <http-basic/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="myAuthenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider">    
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>



    <beans:bean id="myAuthenticationProvider" 
                class="com.siman.store.mobile.service.security.AuthLdapSiman" />

</beans:beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <!-- Paquete en el que estan servicios -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.siman.rms.ipow.web.service.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.siman.rms.ipow</groupId>
    <artifactId>rms-ipow-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>rms-ipow-service</name>


    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> 
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version> 
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                    <clientIncludes>
                        <archive>log4j.properties</archive>
                    </clientIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The configuration at least it is working, but I don't know why is not working the 'authentication-provider' I have tested the example that I have mantioned in the github project but it is running in a tomcat.

When I tested the url in a browser:

http://localhost:7003/store-mobile-service/rest/some

it prompts the http authentication dialog, but it is not taking the users I give to the form, the logs displays:

```
2016-06-28 11:18:14 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/rest/some'; against '/rest/**'
2016-06-28 11:18:14 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /rest/some at position 1 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-06-28 11:18:14 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /rest/some at position 2 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-06-28 11:18:14 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /rest/some at position 3 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2016-06-28 11:18:14 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /rest/some at position 4 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2016-06-28 11:18:14 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /rest/some at position 5 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2016-06-28 11:18:14 DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter:102 - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6faa3d44: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff4c9c: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.24.79; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2016-06-28 11:18:14 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /rest/some at position 6 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2016-06-28 11:18:14 DEBUG FilterChainProxy:337 - /rest/some at position 7 of 7 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2016-06-28 11:18:14 DEBUG AntPathRequestMatcher:145 - Checking match of request : '/rest/some'; against '/rest/**'
2016-06-28 11:18:14 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:194 - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /rest/some; Attributes: [ROLE_REST]
2016-06-28 11:18:14 DEBUG FilterSecurityInterceptor:310 - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@6faa3d44: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff4c9c: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.24.79; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2016-06-28 11:18:14 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:65 - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@52d222cf, returned: -1
2016-06-28 11:18:14 DEBUG AffirmativeBased:65 - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@a0cdfde, returned: 0
2016-06-28 11:18:14 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:165 - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3367)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3333)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2220)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2146)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2124)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1564)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:254)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
2016-06-28 11:18:14 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter:185 - Calling Authentication entry point.
2016-06-28 11:18:14 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:97 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same issue. I was able to get my client to work depending on how I configured my client.

Non working version:

```
 Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(cc);
    Response response = client.target(baseurl)
            .path(targetUrl)
            .request()
            .property(org.glassfish.jersey.client.authentication.HttpAuthenticationFeature.HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC_USERNAME, USER)
            .property(org.glassfish.jersey.client.authentication.HttpAuthenticationFeature.HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC_PASSWORD, PASS)
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .get();
```

Working Version

```
HttpAuthenticationFeature f = HttpAuthenticationFeature
                                                    .basicBuilder()
                                                    .nonPreemptive()
                                                    .credentials(USER, PASS)
                                                    .build();
        ClientConfig cc = new ClientConfig();
        cc.register(f);

        client = ClientBuilder.newClient(cc);
        Response response = client.target(baseurl).path(targetUrl).request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .get();
```

For others who answer. I have a couple of questions.

1. Why is the anonymous authentication chain firing?
2. How do I disable anonymous filter chain?